# $(1+x)/(1-x)>e^{2x}$ using infinite series, $0<x<1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$(1+x)/(1-x)>e^{2x}$ using infinite series, $0<x<1$

so alternatively  $1>\sum x^k(\frac{2^k}{k!}-1)$. I have $\frac{2^k}{k!}>1$

any hints?

Comment: You can't multiply series in that manner.

Comment: Expand $(1-x )^{-1}$ in a Taylor series.  Multiply that by $1+x $, and comepare with $ e^{2x} $.

Answer (score 1):

Since $0<x<1$ we can apply the geometric series on the LHS to find that $$\begin{align*}\frac{1+x}{1-x}&=(1+x)\frac{1}{1-x}=(1+x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)=\\\\&=(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)+(x+x^2+x^3+x^4\ldots)=1+2(x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)\end{align*}$$ 
On the other hand the RHS becomes $$e^{2x}=\left(1+\frac{2x}{1!}+\frac{(2x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(2x)^3}{3!}\dots \right)=\left(1+\frac{2}{1!}x+\frac{2^2}{2!}x^2+\frac{2^3}{3!}x^3\dots \right)$$ Thus $$\begin{align*}\frac{1+x}{1-x}-e^{2x}&=1+2(x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)-\left(1+\frac{2x}{1!}+\frac{(2x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(2x)^3}{3!}\dots \right)=\\\\&=\underbrace{(2-1)}_{>0}x^2+\underbrace{\left(2-\frac{2^3}{3!}\right)}_{>0}x^3+\underbrace{\left(2-\frac{2^4}{4!}\right)}_{>0}x^4+\ldots>0\end{align*}$$ for $0<x<1$ which gives the required inequality, i.e. that $$\frac{1+x}{1-x}-e^{2x}>0 \implies \frac{1+x}{1-x}>e^{2x}$$ for $0<x<1$.

---

Actually we used the fact that $2^n<n!$ for $n\ge 4$. This is straightforward since $$2^4=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2<2\cdot3\cdot4=4!$$ and for $n>4$ the RHS is multiplied with $n-4$ fractors (numbers form $4$ up to $n$) whereas the LHS is multiplied with the same number of factors (however all of which are equal to $2$).

Answer (score 0):

For $-1 <x <1 $, we have
$$\dfrac {1+x}{1-x}=(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + ...)(1+x)=x^5+2x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1 +...$$
We also have
$$ e^{2x}=1+2x+2x^2+\dfrac {4x^3}{3}+\dfrac { 2x^4}{3}+\dfrac {4x^5}{15}+... $$
 Compare the two series in the interval $(0, 1) $. This will prove your statement.

Answer (score 0):

After some arranging with the series,
$$
e^{2x}(1-x)=(1-x)\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2x)^k}{k!}=1+x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{2^{k-1}x^k}{(k-1)!}\,\left(\frac{2x}k-1\right)<1+x.
$$
The inequality is due to the fact that, as $x<1$ and $k\geq2$, $(2x/k-1)<0$.

Comment: There seem to be some errors in your second proof. Both $2x>\frac{2x}{1-x} $ and  $\log\frac{2x}{1-x}=\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ are wrong.

Comment: Yep. Eight years later, I cannot make sense of what I was trying to do. Deleted.