# How to solve $ \frac{1+x}{1-x} > e^{2x} $ properly with differentiation?

Tags: calculus, analysis

So i have
for $ 0 < x < 1$ :

$$ \frac{1+x}{1-x} > e^{2x} $$

My approach:

Let $$ f(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x}-e^{2x} $$

then
$$ f'(x) = \frac{2}{(1-x)^2}-2e^{2x} $$

okay, here i have troubles. I highly assume i need now to show that

$$ 0 < f'(x) < 1 $$

but how do i do that properly? If somebody could show you to continue from here that would help a lot to understand this better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inequality: $\frac{1+x}{1-x} > e^{2x}$ for $0 < x < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588990/inequality-frac1x1-x-e2x-for-0-x-1)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/719096/42969 – both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%2Bx%7D%7B1-x%7D%20%3E%20e%5E%7B2x%7D%24)

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the links. Sorry i didn't saw them earlier, i searched for them but couldn't find anything related

Comment: @MartinR i need to solve this via differentiation. I updated the question and it seems like the links don't really do that. I will continue to do my research in the meantime but have nothing against it if somebody could show me exactly that.

Comment: The answers there do use differentiation. Look at the second answer. He finds the formula for the difference between the two, and takes the derivative of that, proving that it will be >0 for $0<x<1$. This means that it will always be increasing, or greater than 0.

Comment: okay i'll double check

Comment: I’d just compare the power series for the two side. The left side is $$-1+\frac{2}{1-x}$$ has terms $2x^n$ for each $n>0,$ and and $e^{2x}$ has $\frac{2^n}{n!}x^n$ for all $n,$ and $2^n\leq 2n!$ for all $n>0.$